# Package dependencies into jar

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to develop a game plugin (oldschool runescape). I'm trying to add in org.json so that it's easier to read/write game states and stuff, but can't seem to figure out how to get it to package org.json with my plugin. It compiles fine, but doesn't run with that package. Any help?

This is what my plugin.gradle.kts looks like

```
version = "4.0.0"

project.extra["PluginName"] = "Plugin Name"
project.extra["PluginDescription"] = "Misc QOL fixes I wanted"

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies{
    // https://mavenlibs.com/maven/dependency/org.json/json
    compileOnly(group = "org.json", name = "json", version = "20220320")
}
tasks {
    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes(
                mapOf(
                    "Plugin-Version" to project.version,
                    "Plugin-Id" to nameToId(project.extra["PluginName"] as String),
                    "Plugin-Provider" to project.extra["PluginProvider"],
                    "Plugin-Description" to project.extra["PluginDescription"],
                    "Plugin-License" to project.extra["PluginLicense"]
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

edit: I tried compileOnly, implementation, testImplementation, all with the same error "ClassnotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject"

Comment: Look up "fat JAR".

Comment: It may help to use a plugin for this: https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/#benefits-of-shadow

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong configuration, you should use "implementation" instead of "compileOnly" as per this [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html?_ga=2.48695910.1724742884.1652711563-2114432090.1652711563#sec:java_dependency_management_overview).

The gist of it is that "compileOnly" means these libraries are only needed at compiletime, and not at runtime, so they are not included in the jar, as the jar is used at runtime. The "implementation" configuration means these libraries are needed both at compile time and at runtime. Alternatively, you could also use "runtimeOnly" to indicate the package is only needed at runtime, but I don't know if that would work with your project.

Comment: I'll put this in the original post, but didn't think about it at the time, I'll update it there also. I tried compileOnly, implementation, testImplementation, all with the same error "ClassnotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject"